# Should you make an aggressive edit on a post that already has answers?

Tags: discussion, editing

In this question

[Is there a word for someone or something that literally defies the laws of physics?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259246/is-there-a-word-for-someone-or-something-that-apparently-defies-the-laws-of-phys/)

The question was initially badly phrased asking for words meaning something that *really does* defy physics. Initial answers then quite rightly gave answers like 'supernatural', while also pointing out that 'defying physics' wasn't really what was happening.

Later edits by the OP show that these really weren't the answers he's looking for, because he wasn't wanting a deference to magic.

I've since edited the question to reframe it as '*appearing* to defy physics', but this invalidates the other three answers.

Personally I think what should have happened was the original answerers should have edited the question straight away. Given that that hasn't happened, is my edit the best course of action, or is it better to close the question and ask a new one?

Comment: Well, it seems like the OP has a misunderstanding of what "the laws of physics" mean for most people, so this is tough. On the other hand, I feel like those writing answers should have taken into account the example of "magic" sand, which was in the question from the beginning, and which indicates that the OP isn't necessarily talking about things that "literally" defy natural law.

Comment: If you're sure that the changes you're introducing significantly improve the accuracy and clarity of the question, I think that you should proceed with the aggressive edit. However, as a courtesy to people who have answered the earlier (and deeply flawed) original question, I think that you should add a comment beneath each answer that has been pushed off-point by your changes. Doing so will notify the answerer that a review of the original answer may be in order. The most difficult situation involving this sort of thing is in the Review queue, where you can't see any answers that may exist.

Comment: @sumelic Well yes, I think in the end this question in question should be clsoed, as it's not clear what the OP is asking. However, the meta question still remains.